# Finding Large Text Sections

Tags: c#, .net

Does anyone know a way in c# to find given a very large string to find random text sections with are greater than 25 continues chars that are alphanumeric?

I've tried looping though each char but it is too slow.

Comment: Can you also list an example of what chars you are looking for.. IndexOf can be used but if you have a static char you are looking for you could also accomplish this using the Contains() method as well but hard to tell without seeing an example of what Larger String you are trying to seek thru

Comment: it can be any alpha numeric string im trying to find

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you mean?

Comment: I think what you need to clarify what it is you're looking for? Let's say I've got a document that contains the letter 'a' 26 times, and then a space, then the letter 'z' a bajillion times. Is that 1) pick one of the two "words" at random (50% probability), because each are greater than 25, 2) there are a bajillion - 26 substrings of length 26 that are just characters, pick one of them at random (about one in a bajillion chance of picking the 'a' string over a 'z' string. 3) there are on the order of a bajillion squared substrings of length 26+ that are just characters. (1/baj^2 for 'a')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regular expressions:

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(inputString, @"\w{25,}");
foreach(Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

`\w` means "any alphanumeric character", and `{25,}` means "at least 25 repetitions"

Answer (score 1):

C# has optimized the `IndexOf` method, but it still might not be enough for you?

```
var haystack = "The collected works of shakespeare";
var needle = "work";
var index = haystack.IndexOf(needle);
```

Comment: I am wanting random sections not just ones i know

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions suit your needs?  Something along the lines of \w{25,}

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions. For example, the following code:

```
 string s = "a b c def ghij";
 Regex r = new Regex(@"\w{3,}", RegexOptions.Compiled);
 var result = r.Matches(s);
 foreach (Match m in result)
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
```

will write `def` and `ghij` on the screen. `[\w]` is any alphanumeric character, including digits. (You can replace with `[A-Za-z]` if you use latin alphabet and don't want to include digits) `{3,}` part means "3 or more of the preceding".

But this would find all matches, not just random sections. Still it should be fast enough for most purposes. (Certainly faster than iterating char by char) If not, you can try `r.Matches(s, index)` to find matches occuring after index, with index being a random integer less than `s.Length`

If you want to find all matches, and then randomly select a sample among them but find regular expressions too slow you could try to implement Boyer-Moore string searching algorithm (The basic idea is, if a non-alphanumeric character occurs at 25th position, then there is no need to check the first 24 characters, just jump and chech the 50th position), but probably will not beat built in regular expressions anyway.